# Euler method inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Given the problem for $t\neq0$ and $t\le1$
>
> $y'(t)=y^2(t)$
>
> $y(0)=1$
>
> Let $\mu>0$, and $\epsilon_n=\frac12(f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})-f(t_n,y_n))$, such that $|\epsilon_n|\le\mu|y_n|$ is satisfied. Using Euler method show that: $\displaystyle y_n\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_n}$
>    and $t_n\le 1+\sqrt{\mu}$, $\forall n$

First I have solved the problem and obtained $y=\frac1{1-t}$

If I look at the graph, then $y_n\le\frac1{1-t_n}$ for $t_n<1$ because the it is convex and

$y_n\ge\frac1{1-t_n}$ for $t_n>1$, since it is concave.

bu i couldn't combine this result with the condition given above, can you help please, Thanks.

Comment: has nobody an idea, also keywords would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $y_n \ne y(t_n)$ - $y_n$ is obtained by the Euler method. Btw explicit or implicit Euler scheme?

Comment: explicit euler scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y'=y^2\implies f(t_n,y_n)=y_n^2$

Hence

$\epsilon_n=\frac12h_n\left[f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})-f(t_n,y_n)\right]=\frac12\left[ y_{n+1}^2-y_n^2\right]$

The euler method form $t_n$ to $t_{n+1}$ is:

$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_ny_n^2$$\quad$

Squaring both sides gives

$y_{n+1}^2=y_n^2+2h_ny_n^3+h_n^2y_n^4\iff y_{n+1}^2-y_n^2=2h_ny_n^2+h_n^2y_n^2$

$\Rightarrow|\epsilon_n|=|h_ny_n|^2|1+\frac{1}{2}h_ny_n||y_n|\overset {\text{by hypo}}\le\mu|y_n|$

$\Rightarrow h_ny_n\le\sqrt{\mu}\quad(1)$

Now the inequalities can be shown by induction.

$\text{(IH1)}$ $t_0=0\le1+\sqrt{\mu}$

$\text{(IH2)}$ $y_0=1\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-0}=1$

$\underline{\text{(IS)}\ t_{n+1}\le 1+\sqrt{\mu}}:$

$h_n=t_{n+1}-t_{n}\implies t_{n+1}=h_n+t_n\overset {(1)}\le\frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{y_n}+t_n\overset {\text{(IH1)}}\le\frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{y_n}+1+\sqrt{\mu}\overset {\text{(IH2)}}\le \sqrt{\mu}\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_n}{1+\sqrt{\mu}}+t_n=\sqrt{\mu}-\frac{\sqrt{\mu}t_n}{1+\sqrt{\mu}}+t_n=\sqrt{\mu}+\frac{t_n}{1+\sqrt{\mu}}\overset {\text{(IH1)}}\le \sqrt{\mu}+1\small\square$

$\underline{\text{(IS)}\ y_{n+1}\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1}}}:$

$y_{n+1}-\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1}}\overset {\text{euler method}}=y_n+h_ny_n^2-\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1}}\overset {\text{(IH2)}}\ge \frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n}}+h_n\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1}}\right)^2-\frac{1+\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1}}$

$\overset {t_{n+1}=t_n+h_n}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{\mu})^2h_n}{(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_n)^2(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1})}-\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{\mu}\right)h_n}{(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_n)^2(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1})}=\frac{\sqrt{\mu}\left(1+\sqrt{\mu}\right) h_n}{(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_n)^2(1+\sqrt{\mu}-t_{n+1})}\ge 0$ $\small\square$